# c++ include a class from foreign namespace

Tags: c++

I'm new to programming and especially C++ which I'm keen to learn, although out of all the text books or external links I have studied I can't seem to find this.

here goes.

If I have two classes (class A && class B)

Class A has a namespace A_NS;
Class B has a namespace B_NS;

both these classes are located in foreign folders

Class A -> fileA.h (FolderA)
Class B -> fileB.h (FolderB)

---

My Question is:
in class A, how can I `#include<B_NS/fileB.h>`

I want to reference my fileB.h via a sort of common interface? is it the namespace I use here? 
I wouldn't want to use the folder name e.g. `<folderB/fileB.h>`
Because in reality the folder is a few directories down.

I just don't know how to include it, I was wondering if namespace could do it as I have a number of files in different directories I would like coupled under one common type of name, if that makes any sense ^^

Im sorry this is my first post on Stackoverflow and I find it hard to put clearly my issue but if anyone could please provide some help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Specifying your compiler and OS might help here.

Comment: Is include dir option what you are looking for?

Comment: I don't think you mean "namespace".

Comment: I'm using a linux distro & GNU compiler but I thought this was standard in a way. I also build with makefiles and was hoping to couple a number of files under a common name, like common/fileB.h

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wouldn't want to use the folder name

This is compiler-specific, which is probably why your textbooks don't cover it, but all compilers have some way of putting a directory on the include path. With GCC, you'd use the `-I` option:

```
g++ module.cpp -I../headers
```

Namespaces are entirely separate from file paths to modules/headers.

Comment: I see, thank you for that information larsman.  "Namespaces are entirely separate from file paths to modules/headers." <- this has really cleared that up for me :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A class does not have a namespace but is contained in a namespace.
A class being contained in a namespace has no affect on the `#include` directive to include the header file containing the class.

Compilers have switches that allow you to specify folders to be searched when looking for files in `#include` directives.

For example:

> C:\folderA\ClassA.h
>
> C:\folderB\ClassB.h

```
#include <ClassA.h>
#include <ClassB.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler switch `-I` is common for compilers:

```
cl.exe main.cpp -I C:\folderA -I C:\folderB
```

Comment: Thank you hmjd for that example, I see how wrong I was now, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

To specify an extra include directory (i.e. to tell the compiler where to look for include files, in addition to where it already does) depends on which compiler you're using:

**GCC**:

```
g++ -I/path/to/include file.cpp
```

**CL (Visual Studio's Compiler)**:

```
cl file.cpp -I C:/path/to/include
```

You can also set this option in the options for a particular project in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thank you Anthony - I have since added them under a nice directory name "common" ^^ all is working as I wanted now :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess some background on the difference of `#include "file.h"` and `#include <file.h>` might also be useful.

If you define `#include "file.h"` it will start to look in the same directory, then your include paths, while `#include <file.h>` searches the include paths.

Include paths are added through compiler specific ways as @larsmans pointed out, but if you added the root of your project to the include paths, it might work against you.

I maintain all headers files in a separate include folder `include\project\file.h` I then add just `include` to my include path. I then include my headers files by `#include <project\file.h>` and the point of this is that the `project` directory in this case will act as a namespace for your header files. It will be more clear -- if you mix and match header files across projects (which you are bound to do) -- which header file belongs where and you don't risk mixing header files that might share the same file name.